# How to manage PATH

Tags: nushell

I'd like to be able to easily/often change my `PATH` environment variable interactively. In other shells, this is really easy; eg, appending with Zsh:

```
path+=/some/path
```

With Nushell, [the docs say](https://www.nushell.sh/book/configuration.html#path-configuration) the equivalent is:

```
$env.PATH = ($env.PATH | split row (char esep) | append '/some/path')
```

That's kinda crazy to have to type for an interactive shell. But this also seems to work, and is *almost* reasonable:

```
let-env PATH = ($env.PATH|append /some/path)
```

*(BTW, why do docs mention both `$env.PATH = ...` and `let-env PATH = ...` approaches? Which is preferred and why?)*

To make it more reasonable, it feels something like this is needed (in my `config.nu`), but I'd like to know: **is this approach fine for appending to `PATH`?**

```
def-env path-append [d] { let-env PATH = ($env.PATH | split row (char esep) | append $d) }
...
path-append /some/path
```

Additionally, **is this the right way to *remove* an entry from `PATH`**?

```
$env.PATH # see that entry 37 is unwanted
let-env PATH = ($env.PATH|drop nth 37) # remove 37th entry

# so then this is even better (also in my config.nu)?
def-env path-drop [n] { let-env PATH = ($env.PATH|drop nth $n) }
path-drop 37
```

BONUS: Zsh has `vared` to interactively edit things like `PATH`. Is there any such equivalent in Nu?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that the docs you are referring to for adding to the Path are assuming that you are doing it at startup, via `env.nu`.  The docs also mention that the reason for the `split row (char esep)` step is:

> because in `env.nu`, the environment variables inherited from the host process are still strings. The conversion step of environment variables to Nushell values happens after reading the config files (see also the [Environment](https://www.nushell.sh/book/environment.html#environment-variable-conversions) section).

And I'm separating out the most important sentence here:

> After that, for example in the Nushell REPL when `PATH/Path` is a list , you can use `append/prepend` directly.

So, *interactively* (a.k.a., *"in the Nushell REPL"*), you can shorten it to:

```
$env.PATH = ($env.PATH | append '/some/path')
```

> why do docs mention both `$env.PATH = ...` and `let-env PATH = ...` approaches? Which is preferred and why?

If there's a section of the docs that still refers to `let-env`, you should open an issue against that (or a PR), since `let-env` has been removed from Nushell in recent releases.  `$env` was made mutable, so there is no reason for `let-env` any longer.

> is this approach fine for appending to `PATH`?

For interactive use, remove the `split...` portion as mentioned above.  Also use `$env`:

```
def-env path-append [d] { $env.PATH = ($env.PATH | append $d) }
```

> is this the right way to remove an entry from `PATH`?

Sure, that will work, assuming you make the same modifications as above (`$env` instead of `let-env`).

You might get fancier if you'd like with something like:

```
def-env path-remove [d] {
    $env.PATH = ( $env.PATH | 
        each {|p|
            if $p != $d { $p }
        }
    )
}
```

Then you could call `path-remove /some/path`

> Zsh has `vared` to interactively edit things like `PATH`. Is there any such equivalent in Nu?

Not that I can think of.  `$env.PATH | explore` would give you a nice *read-only* view, but not really any improvement in this case over the default table-view.  However, there's no equivalent that I can think of for editing.